# Core Data reflexive to-many relationships

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Need to set up an Entity Person that has a to-many relationship to itself (reflexive).

So each Person can have n sub person, basicly this:

[image]

Does Person have two Relationships, person and sub_person? How does the inverse rule work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you have to define only one entity *Person*, and two relationships:

- `sub_persons` as to-many relationship from *Person* to *Person*,
- `super_person` as to-one relationship from *Person* to *Person*,

and define these as inverse relationships of each other.

Comment: Correct. The inverse of sub_persons is super_person, and the inverse of super_person is sub_person.

Comment: ok, thanks Martin R. you answered my question for reflexive to-many and many-to-many relationships and i appreciate it. I'm now trying to figure out which i actually need. Could you take a look at my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918556/core-data-and-reflexive-entity-relationships-to-one-or-to-many

Comment: @Log139: Ramy Al Zuhouri's answer to that question is correct: You have a many-to-many relationship. He only mixed up sub_friend and super_friend.

Answer (score 2):

An entity can certainly be related to itself, in the same way that a node in a doubly linked list has *next* and *previous* relationships with other nodes. Remember that an entity is like a class -- it's a *kind of object* rather than a particular object. So, for example, your Person entity might have a *friends* relation to Person -- a given person may have many friends, all of whom are also instances of Person.

Comment: "I don't think Core Data handles many-to-many relations" - that is definitely wrong, see [Many-to-Many Relationships](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW10).

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to have a object in Core Data related to itself in this way. In the Table, Graph editor for the data model, hold down the control key and draw a line out from Person and back to itself. This will give you a line with an arrow on each end, both pointing at Person. Then rename the relationships (parentPerson, subPersons) and make subPersons  a to-many relationship in the property inspector. The end result should look like this:

[image]

This style of data management follows a design pattern known as the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).