# Core Data and Reflexive Entity relationships (to-one or to-many)

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Trying to setup a Entity relationship but having difficulty figuring out a relationship i need:

I have a single Entity, Person. Person has two relationships, super_friend and sub-friend. Each Entity can have many friends (a Person Entity), so sub_friend is to-many relationship. I am not sure what super_friend is; a to-one or a to-many relationship.

Example: Bill is friends with Fred and Ted. Alice is also friends with Fred.

does this mean Fred's super_friend needs to be to-many?

EDIT:

Entity Person Bill's sub_friend points to Fred and Ted.

Entity Person Alice's sub_friend points to Fred.

so what relationship does Fred's super_friend have to Entity Bill and Entity Alice? If I pull up Entity Fred, will it only point to Bill or Alice?

I think that just answered my question. I would need Entity Fred to point to both Bill and Alice, so to-many. I want each Entity to be Unique.

What if i don't care about who Fred's super_friends are? i would only ever transverse "down" through sub_friends, never "back up" through super_friend/s.

EDIT 2:

Due to confustion let me expand my need: i need to sortive transverse the Entities.

So say I am Bill, i need to see who all Bill's sub_friends (Fred and Ted). I select Fred. I then need to find all of Fred's sub_friends and select one, etc. I need to be able to do this n times.

A solution with just a friend relationship would not allow me to keep the friends separate. Say Fred knows John and Stacy. When i query Fred, i won't know if John is above (super_friend and won't care about) or if John is a sub_friend (need to present in a table view for selection).

Comment: Are you asking us whether a person can have many "super_friends" or not? How should we know? What does super_friend represent?

Comment: super_friend is the relationship back to a Person entity.

Comment: Still don't really get it. But everyone else seems to understand so that's fine... I'm out :)

Comment: In your example, for clarification, is Bill supposed to be to be the super_friend of Fred?  Is Alice a sub_friend of Fred?

Comment: Yes, Bill is the super_friend of Fred, but Alice is also the super_friend of Fred. Bill and Alice have no relationship to each other.

Comment: As I already stated, I dont understand your whole sub/super friend concept and the design is of course up to you. But from a common-sense standpoint, isnt it logical that if Bill is friend with Fred that also Fred is friends with Bill. So in core-data terms I would have a friends relationship that points to a Person entity and is an inverse to-many relationship?

Comment: It sounds like you just need one `friend` relationship that is many-to-many, plain and simple.

Comment: Mario made a valid point here: Speaking of "friends" implies a "symmetric relationship": If A is friend with B, then B is friend with A. But Core Data has (as far as I know) no mechanism to maintain the symmetry of a relationship ("inverse relationships" are something different). If you need this symmetry, then you have to manage that yourself. Otherwise it might be clearer to use different names for the relationships, e.g. "likes" and "is_liked_by". As we all know, "likes" is not a symmetric relationship!

Comment: Didnt use core-data or dbms in general too extensively to call myself an expert, so @MartinR : why isnt what you described an inverse relationship? And what is the difference to a symmetric relationship. But maybe this discussion exceeds the confines of a comment-section.

Comment: @MartinR having `likes` and `liked_by` is really easy and a *very* common scenario. Or I'm missing your point entirely.

Comment: @MartinR to elaborate: both would me marked 'to-many' so you'd have a many-to-many relationship. In the underlying sqlite store you will then find an extra join table for this, as you would expect.

Comment: @Mario: I have to correct myself. In general you have two relationships which are inverse to each other. But a relationship can also be inverse to itself (like you said in your answer), then you get a symmetric relationship. - I am really sorry for the confusion. I should stop to comment on other peoples answers ...

Comment: @MartinR no harm done... und viele Grüße

Comment: @mvds: I know what a many-to-many relationship is. My point was that a many-to-many relationship is in general not symmetric, and that naming the relationships "likes" and "is_liked_by" instead of "sub_friend" and "super_friend" might make things clearer. But it seems that I only increased the confusion, and I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at this diagram:

[image]

Like you see Bill has many sub_friend's, and Fred is sub_friend of many entities.
So it's a to-many relationship.

**EDIT**

I thought it was pretty obvious, but sub_friend is the reverse relationship of super_friend, because if Bill has Fred as sub_friend, then fred has Bill as super_friend.

Comment: If you replace "super_friend" by "sub_friend" then this is (in my opinion) the correct answer (+1).

Comment: You are right, but I would precisate that I posted the answer before he edited it, and he said: "Example: Bill is friends with Fred and Ted. Alice is also friends with Fred", it was ambiguous so I assumed that "friend with Fred" meant that he had a super_friend relationship with Fred.Correctly edited it.

Comment: Well in his original question he already knew that "sub_friend" is a to-many relationship :) he asked for super_friend

Comment: @Mario super_friend is the reverse of sub_friend, thus this answers the question.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri if you look at my answer and comments, I've been saying that all along. So to be totally pedantic, this is not the answer to the question, since it states the same thing the OP did - albeit with a nice picture :) (which doesnt show the inverse relationship or states that super_friend should be inverse to sub_friend btw)

Comment: I already changed once the picture.Now I should change it, write super_friend instead of sub_friend, reversing the arrows? I'll just edit it writing that they're the reverse, which I thought to be obvious.

Comment: It isn't obvious. It was exactly the OP's question: "so sub_friend is to-many relationship. I am not sure what super_friend is; a to-one or a to-many relationship."

Answer (score 2):

As I already stated, I dont understand your whole sub/super friend concept and the design is of course up to you. But from a common-sense standpoint, isnt it logical that if Bill is friend with Fred that also Fred is friends with Bill. An they are both Person entities. So in core-data terms I would have a friends relationship that points to a Person entity and is an inverse to-many relationship?

Look at this Core-Data Entity: [image]

In the inspector of the relation you see an inverse to-many relationship:

[image]

Comment: This may work, but i need to be able to separate the people below (sub_friend) and above (super_friend). I need to find Bill's sub_friends (Fred and Ted), user selects Fred and then i need to find all of Fred's sub_friends. I didn't mention this part and i should have, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Mario: I have similar requirement where a category can have multiple sub-categories and it can also have further sub-categories. I have created relationship to self same as above entity diagram. But, when I generated Model for that entity I am facing error as "Redefinition of 'Category' as different kind of symbol". Any suggestions what can create such issue?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that sub_friend and super_friend are inverses of each other then sub_friend is a 1:n relationship, super_friend is a 1:1. If you substitute 1 for n, because you are looking at one entity, then you get 1:1, a single entity can only reference to one super.

In terms of properties the sub_friends would turn into an NSSet, whereas the super_friend would be a Person *.

Comment: The inverse of a to-many relationship can also be a to-many relationship, see [Many-to-Many Relationships](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW10). I think this applies here.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, your comment just answered your own question =)  You just said Fred has 2 super_friends.  Clearly a many relationship.

Expanding a bit more: I changed your relationship names in my brain, because as far as I can tell, sub_friend just means an immediate friend, and super_friend means a friend of a friend.

The many relationship naturally fits, because nothing would make sense if you had only 1 friend of a friend.